# (how) Can I JOIN SELECTs from multiple databases into a DBgrid?

Tags: mysql, delphi, tdbgrid

I have separate MySQL database servers.

How can I JOIN the data from queries to the databases on these servers, and show it on a DBgrid?

[Answer]  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Comment: Is the question "how can I show data that doesn't exist"?

Comment: @Jan - Your edit probably hides the fact that there are no connection between servers. If that is the case that is.. Also in which case the question definitely is not a duplicate.

Comment: You either make the servers available so that you can write a single query to access them (in SQLServer it's as a linked server), or you create a temp table on the local machine, select from each server into those temp tables, merge the tables (even if it's one row at a time via a table), and then query the local data.

Comment: @Sertac I went back to the original question but don't read that. What he writes is that one central server is out of the question because the four locations want to have their servers in-house.

Comment: @Jan - In that case, your edit is fine. :)

Comment: How many fields are we stitching together and how large is the dataset?  It might be practical to load all the datasets to the client and provide calculated fields on the 'master', or as Max suggests - populate a ClientDataset

Answer (score -1):

I have different queries and combine it manually in a `TClientDataSet`.

Comment: This is not an answer, unless you edit it to add much more detail. As is, it's a comment to the question.

Comment: -1. This answer should be deleted in the actual formulation.

Comment: @max, +1 not highly infomative, but it's a starting point for me. Thanks